# How to detect backlight is on?

Tags: android

My application requires resource and drains a battery when it is working. So, I want to know the way that user is not available on the phone.

Is there a way to use the built in power save mode on the blackberry to where if the screen dims to suspend the application works active and when the user wakes the device back up with a keypress or trackball movement to resume the application works active?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you suggest me any API doc related this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the built in
>   power save mode on the blackberry to
>   where if the screen dims to suspend
>   the application works active and when
>   the user wakes the device back up with
>   a keypress or trackball movement to
>   resume the application works active?

This happens automatically, with no code changes required. Unless something is holding a `WakeLock`, the CPU will turn off sometime after the screen goes dark. The CPU will turn back on when the user presses the power button.